# What installation strategies exists for deploying distributed applications to cloud?

Tags: deployment, vagrant

We develop distributed system that features few computation nodes(Windows), database, queue and some other components. Also system uses some Azure specific configurations. Our current deployment is set of scripts that provision system to the Azure.

I am facing requirement for product to be sellable and those installable to customer's Azure environment or event on-prem virtualized environments.

I can see few options here:

1. Use MSI or something like this to install each component. Unfortunately, this does not help to orchestrate nodes (VMs) and leads to quite tedious manual procedure of instantiating VMs and then configuring each.
2. Use Vagrant, main problem with this option is requirement for customer to have knowledge of Vagrant. Another problem is huge sizes of Windows images and licensing problems (this is not apply to deployment procedure itself because AMIs, but hurts development).
3. Use cmd/powershell scripts for installation. This option again requires to much knowledge from customers.

So the questions are:
1. Is there any best practices here?
2. What technics are used? What tools?

Please do not hesitate to add answers that apply to Linux or to Azure. This will help find best solution, or may be direction to best solution.